# Type Mismatch: Cannot convert from Int to Double in Monte Carlo Bayesian Experiment in Anylogic

Tags: anylogic

I am working on a Monte Carlo Bayesian Experiment for Gonorrhea disease. I am trying to plot the values of a collection (int, TreeMap) at the end of the experiment run. But it returns the following error

Type Mismatch: Cannot convert from Int to Double in Monte Carlo Bayesian Experiment in Anylogic

[image]

As mentioned by Mr. Felipe in the previous question, I Created a new collection called mcIncidences of type (Int, TreeMap)

Now at the after experiment run I want to plot the values of mcIncidences in a timeplot chart. I wrote the following code,

`for(Integer iteration: mcIncidences.keySet()){ double incidence = mcIncidences.get(iteration); IncidenceDS.add(1, incidence); }`

But doing so returns the following error,

`Type Mismatch: Cannot convert from Int to Double in Monte Carlo Bayesian Experiment in Anylogic`

[image]

[image]

Comment: As per  Felipe earlier: There are a ton of misconceptions in your setup, leading to this one error. I suggest you start a lot simpler from scratch: use a simple `int` number you want to save from a model run. Store that in your experiment for each run. Plot it. Then (and only then!) add more complexity like a more advanced data type. Always start extremely simple and only add complexity later, else you put yourself into a dead-end like here :)